# How to map Gatsby custom schema type to different nodes inside a specific source?

Tags: gatsby

I'm following some of the instructions from https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-03-04-new-schema-customization/ and I'd like to make some custom Type with special resolvers to resolve relationships between different flat file types. I'm using gatsby-source-filesystem and remark transformer, but I don't see any way to use the node API to assign some files to one type and other files to a different type unless I filter/apply based on sourceInstanceName. Is there a better way to differentiate between nodes from different sources?

Example: I have two types of content, Landing Pages, and Promo blocks, stored in src/content/landing-pages and src/content/promo-blocks. Landing pages can reference Promo blocks and I'd like to modify the schema for each to show the correct relationship between the two and add resolvers to query across the relationships. I have a separate source for both in gatsby-config, but all the items seem to end up in the allFile or allMarkdownRemark.

Should I just add the resolvers to all items in allMarkdownRemark, regardless of whether or not the relationship is valid for that file? How can I differentiate different schemas for separate files in the allFile or allMarkdownRemark types?

Comment: Hi Mikey, I'm having a hard time trying to understand, would you mind explain a bit more? Some pseudo code / diagram example would be helpful

Comment: Thanks @DerekNguyen, I updated to provide an example description, I'll try to add a diagram shortly